# Child UL load adjacent to Parent UL in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap menu and when i mouse over the header it loads a list, when i mouse over one of the menu items it loads a sub menu.

What I want is the first line in the sub menu to be positioned directly adjacent right of the menu item it is under.

so in the below example, when you mouse over header on it loads line one and tow, when you mouse over line one it loads line one a and b

I want line on a to be right of line one.  Also, when you load the sub menu you can't mouse over the menu again it collapses.

css

```
    body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Override the default bootstrap behavior where horizontal description lists 
   will truncate terms that are too long to fit in the left column 
*/
.dl-horizontal dt {
    white-space: normal;
}

/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
.ullevelone{
    display: inline-flex;
    list-style-type: none; 
}

.lilevelone{
    color: red;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.ulleveltwo {
    display: none;          
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;      
}

.lilevelone:hover > .ulleveltwo{
    display: block;
}

.ullevelthree {
    display: none;    
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.lileveltwo:hover > .ullevelthree{
    display: block;
}
```

html

```
<ul class="ullevelone">
                <li class="lilevelone">
                    Header one
                    <ul class="ulleveltwo">
                        <li class="lileveltwo">
                            <a href="">Line one</a>
                            <ul class="ullevelthree">
                                <li class="lilevelthree"><a href="">Line one a </a></li>
                                <li class="lilevelthree"><a href="">Line two a</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="lileveltwo"><a href="">Line two</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="lilevelone">Header two</li>
                <li class="lilevelone">Header three</li>
            </ul>
```

js fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/Lz847txg/

Answer (score 0):

changed:

```
.ullevelone{
    display: inline-flex;
    list-style-type: none; 
    position: relative;
}

.ulleveltwo {
    display: none;          
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none; 
    position: absolute;    

}

.ullevelthree {
    display: none;    
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;    
    list-style-type: none;   
    float: right;   
}



.lileveltwo:hover > .ullevelthree{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

and seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
.ullevelthree {
display: none;    
padding: 0px;
list-style-type: none;
position:absolute;
left:20%;}
```

Comment: With my posted code or with the changes i posted i made?  tried it to see the difference with the changes and it doesn't work